# How to decouple user Identity from the application data

Tags: asp.net, database-design, architecture, oauth-2.0, authorization

I am part of a new startup with some friends from school, and I am developing a REST API as back-end for a web application/website. I have recently gratuated and does not have much experience with large projects.

Without going in detail about the specific business idea, it will be sort of a "share economy" service, like for example uber or airbnb, where users register as either a customer or provider of a specific service. So users need to register an account and have data related to that account.

The API is developed with ASP.NET Web API. For authentication/authorization I am using ASP.NET Identity and JWT as Oauth bearer tokens with OWIN OAuth middleware.

I have used a guide for part of the setup, with some changes to fit our
project. (Just search "bitoftech Implement OAuth JSON Web Tokens Authentication in ASP.NET Web API and Identity 2.1" to find it if you are interested).

For those that don't know, the ASP.NET Identity database looks like this:
[ASP.NET Identity database diagram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG9fF.png)

So we have an AppUser table that represents the user, with roles, claims and logins attached in different tables in the Identity database.

Now, the user has much other data related to his account in our application, like messages (users can message each other), events (like a ride if this was uber), categories, reviews, files, and other data. All in separate tables.

So, since all these other tables are related to the user identity, what I did was put all these other tables in the same database with a Foreign Key to the Id in the AppUser table.

Each user has a role of either Customer or Provider (as in customer or driver in the Uber example) in the IdentityRole table.
This way I can authorize users based on role, and also query data based on role.

Now for the catch: Unexpected requirement changes. The company has decided that they (we) want to create a similar service (with customers and providers), but in a different business domain, and with the same user identity. So users that have already registered with one site should not be required to register again with a new account for the other site, but just use their existing account (and maybe sign up for the new site by clicking a button in their profile or something).

So if the first site was uber, now we want to create airbnb (not really, but as an example).

The data in the new site will be very similar to the first site. Users will have messages, events, categories, files, etc. But the events table will maybe be a little different, and maybe some new or different tables for the new site. We will try to keep the data very similar at first, so we can use much of the existing code, but we expect – if the the site(s) become popular – that they will drift apart (in terms of code and data) in time.

So first I thought: "how can I change the existing database schema so that it will fit both services?". But as I thought more about it, I think this will maybe only create problems in the future.

In the [Oauth flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzViO.png), you have a separate resource server and authorization server. Even though I use Oauth now, my API is both a Resource Server and Authorization Server I guess, and that would probably be ok if they had not had been coupled in the way I have described?

**So my question after all this is this is:**

**1:** *Should I use one (separate) database for the User Identity (IdentityDbContext),
and another database for all the other data (events, messsages etc..)?*

That way Identity can run on a totally different server if need be, and not be coupled to any specific domain/site/service. Is that a good idea?

**2:** *If so, how would I create a relationship between databases?*

The only thing I can think of is to create a separate user table with only the UserId (from the Identity database) in the "Uber" database, and this will be created the first time a user registers for a site, and all the other data is related to this key. Then I would need to query data from two databases and put them together for some operations, for example, when a user queries his incoming messages, the message itself would be in one database and the name of the sender in another. Is there a better way?

**3:** *Should I use separate databases for the first and second website/service (One for Uber and one for Airbnb, as in the example)? Or is there a better way?*

**4:** *Is there a different solution that I have not thought about that would be better?*

Many people have probably faced these problems before, so I would appreciate if any experienced developers could tell me what is the best practice.

Last, it is not unprobable that even more services will be "attached" to the user Identity in the future if our current endevours are successful, so I really need a future-proof solution to this problem.

Thank you for any responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach seems somewhat common:

1. Maintain a completely separate identity database.  There should be no connection at all with any of the Line-Of-Business (LOB) databases.
2. Each LOB database should have its own user table, with appropriate referential integrity constraints with other LOB tables, e.g. events or messages in your case.
3. When a user hits one of your LOB web sites for the first time, he should be "enrolled" in the LOB database.  A LOB user record is inserted.  Use the access token to call the identity server to get any demographic information your LOB site will need.
4. When a user hits one of your LOB web sites for the Nth time, you can use the access token to call the identity server and get the most recent, up-to-date demographic information, just in case any of it has changed since his last visit. You can then store this information in the LOB user table so that it is available to you offline, e.g. if you need to push marketing emails you'll have a copy of the email address.

The advantage of this approach is separation of concerns and the ability to support more than one authentication provider (e.g. in the future you could support Facebook or Google+ logins as well).

Also you avoid any dependencies between the identity server and the LOB servers, so you can add or remove lines of business as needed, and you keep the identity server nice and lightweight.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just a couple of questions: The API (LOB server) is completely stateless, so how would the server know if a user hits it for the Nth time?  Wouldn't it be easier to let the identity server notify the LOB server every time a user record is altered? Maybe some kind of observer pattern? Or would that break the separation of concerns? And should I use completely separate databases for each Line of Business (as in my third question)?

Comment: The LOB application would know a user is new due to the lack of any record in the LOB User table.  If you are selling these solutions separately, you will want to avoid any dependencies between them (other than a dependency on the login protocol, which is unavoidable).

Comment: My question was referring to the Nth time a user hits the server, not the first time (you said I could call the identity server periodically – i.e. the Nth time – to check if the user information has been updated). So how would I accomplish that? Thanks.

Comment: Using the inverse logic.  If a record already exists in the User table, perform the update.  Basically, `if not exists then insert else update`.